# Unable to understand and fix problem LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Web Component called `simpleTable` and another Aura Component which references it.

When I try to use LWC component inside of Aura component like following

```
<aura:component >
    <c:SimpleTable/> 
</aura:component>
```

> force-app\main\default\aura\SimpleEmployeeList\SimpleEmployeeList.cmp 
>   Compilation Failure
>
> /c/SimpleTable/simpleTable.js:0,0 : LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry
>   for module "simpleTable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like LWC references are case-sensitive and they should be referenced in the exact case like following

```
<aura:component >
    <c:simpleTable/> 
</aura:component>
```

While if we have Aura component called `abc` we can reference it in other components or apps as `Abc` or `ABC` without any errors, for LWC component this simply doesn't work.